# ¿Como generar archivos xml con angular?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angularjs

Necesito de su ayuda, estoy buscando como puedo crear archivos .xml en angular, pero quiero generarlos con la información que viene de mi bd, he buscado y hasta el momento no he encontrado mucho, como para poderme guiar, agradecería su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

No se pueden crear, borrar o modificar archivos desde el cliente, en este caso angularjs, pero si desde nodejs (servidor).

Puedes crear archivos xml con [xmlbuilder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmlbuilder) `npm install --save xmlbuilder` y guardarlos usando `fs`, ejemplo:

```
const fs = require('fs');

var builder = require('xmlbuilder');

var xml = builder.create('root')
  .ele('nodoPadre')
    .ele('unhijo', {'type': 'algo'}, 'Hola mundo')
  .end({ pretty: true});

fs.writeFile("test.xml", xml, function(err) {
    if(err) {
        return console.log(err);
    }

    console.log("Archivo guardado");
});
```

Lo anterior te generará un archivo **test.xml** con el siguiente contenido:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <nodoPadre>
    <unhijo type="algo">Hola mundo</unhijo>
  </nodoPadre>
</root>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias vale la aclaracion, voy a crear una ruta para generar los xml ;)